# Create sibling file name in Python

Tags: python, filenames, idioms

What is the idomatic/canoncial/best way to get a sibling file (name) in Python 2.7?

That is, if there is file like `'C:\\path\\file.bin'` or `'/path/file.bin'`,
how to get `'C:\\path\\anothername.anotherext'` or `'/path/anothername.anotherext'`.

String manipulation, searching for last path separator and replacing the part after that, would of course work, but this seems awfully crude.

In other words, what is idiomatic Python equivalent(s) of these Java snippets:

```
File sibling = new File(file.getParent(), siblingName);
```

Or a bit longer for pathname strings:

```
String siblingPathName = new File(new File(filePathName).getParent(), siblingName).toString();
```

Note: Java being used above is not relevant to the question.

Note2: If Python 3 has a new way, it would be nice to know that too, even though I'm using Python 2.7 atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`os.path.dirname`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) to get the directory of the file, and then [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to add the sibling's name.

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(f), siblingname)
```